# Dart Extension: dynamically index for List

Tags: list, dart, extension-methods

Can you give me some proposals about make an dynamic index extension for a List object in Dart

Below is what I mean:

```dart
final List<String> myList = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

// by default, get an value at [index] belike:
myList[1];

// but what I want to implement belike:
myList.1;
myList.0;
myList.2;
myList.5; // ==> will throw exception
```

Maybe they're look stupid but for me, it's so cool and fancy coding style

Thanks for all your helps & suggestions

Comment: No.  Just no.  That's not gonna happen.  You can add methods to respond to any undefined method you try, but WHY?

Comment: The Dart grammar does not allow identifiers to start with numbers, so it's not possible to do exactly what you describe.  If you *really* wanted, you could use code generation to generate extension a fixed number of getters named, say, `index0`, `index1`, etc. that simply invoke `this[0]`, `this[1]`, etc.  Doing so, however, would be a terrible idea since it wouldn't work for arbitrarily large indices, and it would make your code less readable and more convoluted for no gain.

Answer (score -1):

```
import 'package:amra/amra.dart' as amra;

void main(List<String> arguments) {

MyList._0;
MyList._1;
MyList._2;



  }
class MyList{
static List<String> myList = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
static String _0(){
return MyList.myList[0];
}
static String _1(){
 return MyList.myList[1];
}
static String _2(){
 return MyList.myList[2];
}




  }
```

Comment: Problems with this "answer": Not an answer to the question, badly formatted code, unneeded import, does not scale.

Comment: sorry all i am leave from this platform . i am very unhappy from this comment........

Comment: You are not forced to contribute on this site and I am not forced to pack my critique in fluff just to make sure your feeling are not hurt. I suggest learning from my comment instead of just being "unhappy". I know that you just wanted to help but it is important to do a minimum amount of quality check before posting like e.g. ensuring your code are looking presentable and nice. Dart comes with a builtin code formatter and I suggest you do a bare minimum at least using that feature before posting your code. Your code should also be short and straight to the point without fluff.

Comment: But that does not change the problem of your code does not scale since you are forced to write those index functions for each possible index you want to request from the list. Another problem is then that `_`-prefixed members means "private" in Dart, so you can't really make a library that contains this feature since all your `_` methods would be hidden.

Comment: And at last, you should really read the comments on the question (before working on a solution) where you can see multiple people telling this is a terrible idea in the first place. So you have ended up spending time creating a solution based on a design which are deemed terrible. So you can't really then complain getting critique for this solution and a downvote since this solution is exactly the kind of solution there have been discouraged.